# Airflow not show the overwrited values on config list command (EmailOperator dag case)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I was trying to setup the EmailOperator of Airflow to finish my pipeline with a notification. Following the various steps I found this problem:
Aiflow is not actually showing the variables I passed through the `environment` key in docker. It seems to update it but there is no way to print (for check/verify) them if not by testing directly the task.
Indeed, the `airflow config list`  command is not usefull and retrive the default values.
The problem is extended to the variable like `AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor` that the default docker (created by the airflow team) is builded with.
Is there any solution to this?

Given the airflow docker compose from the official api [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.8.4/docker-compose.yaml)

I tried to add few variables for a simple mail send:

- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: smtp.gmail.com
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: xxx@gmail.com
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: xxx
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: 587
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: xxx@gmail.com

I also changed the property `AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES` to `false` to see a difference in the gui.

Here the code:

```
`x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.8.4}
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session"
    #  OTHER VARIABLE HERE
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: smtp.gmail.com
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: xxx@gmail.com
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: xxx
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: 587
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: xxx@gmail.com
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: "true"
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on: &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy`
```

After running the `docker compose up --build` Im trying to list the properties to check the result with the command: `airflow config list`
The result is (always):

```
[core]
load_examples = True
[smtp]
smtp_host = localhost
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
\# smtp_user = 
\# smtp_password = 
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from = airflow@example.com
smtp_timeout = 30
smtp_retry_limit = 5
```

The fact is that if go in the gui i actually dont see the examples, And i can send the mail too. So everithing works, but the `aiflow config list` or the `airflow config get-value` returns the old values. Why that? How can i actually check the properties?

Comment: No idea where you run `airflow config list`, you do not provide this information.  If you use [Non-production docker-compose file](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#fetching-docker-compose-yaml) you might try to run `docker compose run airflow-cli config list`

Comment: I was erroneusly executing it on project folder. Thanks for the tip, it works.